# Can't get value until pattern matches in a required input field

Tags: html, angularjs

Using AngularJs, I'm trying to store the input field's value to `$scope.newPassword` but it only works after I have typed at least 6 characters. Is it the default behavior or is there any way to handle it?

Here's some code:

**HTML**

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="new-password" ng-model="newPassword" name="new-password" required pattern=".{6,}">
```

**JS**

```
app.controller('validationController', function($scope) {
       $scope.noMatch = false;
       $scope.newPassword="";
       $scope.confirmNewPassword="";
       $scope.passMatchTest = function(){
           if($scope.newPassword!=$scope.confirmNewPassword){
               $scope.noMatch = true;
               $("#new-password, #confirm-new-password").css("background-color", "#f0b9b9");
           }else{
               $scope.noMatch = false;
               $("#new-password, #confirm-new-password").css("background-color", "#aff3af");
           }
       };
       $scope.$watch("newPassword", function(){
           console.log($scope.newPassword);
           $scope.passMatchTest();

       });
       $scope.$watch("confirmNewPassword", function(){
           console.log($scope.confirmNewPassword);
           $scope.passMatchTest();
       });
   });
```

`console.log` shows undefined unless there are more than 6 characters.

Comment: if you don't want any condition remove pattern=".{6,}" from markup

Answer (score 2):

Angular will stop reflecting invalid value by default when using `pattern` or `ng-pattern`. you can add `ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}"` which will allow invalid value to be populated to `ng-model`.

```
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="new-password" ng-model="newPassword" name="new-password" required pattern=".{6,}" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid: true}">
```